# JQuery tablesorter textextraction without sorting the table

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I want to use the textExtract function without sorting the table.

```
 $('.div .input-text.qty').change(function () {
         $("#contract_details").tablesorter({
             textExtraction: function (node) {
                 return $(node).find('.val').text();
             }
        });
    });
```

when I do this the table still sorts.

Comment: is this help full https://jsfiddle.net/12cu0Lg7/1/

Comment: hi @ArvindMaurya, I reviewed the jsfiddle you attached but sadly it doesn't. I want to attach a textExtract function on click or on change without sorting the table. using the .tablesorter automatically sorts the table (at least that what I think).

Comment: can you please elaborate where you are stuck or putting on some working fiddle will be very helpful

Comment: The header class names were missing in that demo. Try it now: https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/k452c60u/2/